# How can I check for a null inside of a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
protected IEnumerable<string> GetErrorsFromModelState() {

    var exceptions = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
        .Select(error => error.Exception.Message));

    var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
        .Select(error => error.ErrorMessage));

    return exceptions.Union(errors);
}
```

Is there a way that I could stop this giving a nullReference Exception if:

```
error.Exception is null  or if error.Exception.Message is null
```

Both cases are giving me problems and I'm not sure how I can code this
with a IsNullOrEmpty check for **both** cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
protected IEnumerable<string> GetErrorsFromModelState()
{        
    var exceptions = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
                            .Where(error => (error != null) && 
                                            (error.Exception != null) &&
                                            (error.Exception.Message != null))
                            .Select(error => error.Exception.Message));

    var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors
                            .Where(error => (error != null) && 
                                            (error.ErrorMessage != null))
                            .Select(error => error.ErrorMessage));

    return exceptions.Union(errors);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this works good. Couple of spelling errors with Exeception :-)

Comment: I would leave out the `Exception.Message` check. If an exception somewhere is having its message set to null, I want to know about that bug so I can track it down at source.

Answer (score 2):

Add in a `.Where(error.Exception != null && error.Exception.Message != null)` before your select to only include ones where the values you want are not `null`.

Comment: Then add that to I, before what I answered with

Answer (score 2):

You could use [May be Monad](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/maybemonads.aspx), First write an static class and put `With`
extension method in that class, then simply use `With` method. In the link there are some other similar types which are also helpful.

```
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, 
       Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
       where TResult : class where TInput : class
{
  if (o == null) return null;
  return evaluator(o);
}
```

And use it simply:

```
var exceptions = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.With(y=>y.Value).With(z=>z.Errors))
        .Select(error => error.With(e=>e.Exception).With(m=>m.Message));
```

**Update:** for making more clear (similar sample also exists in link), assume you have `Person` class hierarchy:

```
public class Person
{
   public Address Adress{get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
   public string PostCode{get;set;}
}
```

Now you want to get person's related post code and you don't know input person is null or not:

```
var postCode = 
// this gives address or null, if either person is null or its address
person.With(x=>x.Address) 
// this gives post code or returns null, 
// if previous value in chain is null or post code is null 
      .With(x=>x.PostCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter out the nulls, then `.Where(error => error.Exception != null)`  (the `Exception` object should always have a non-null message, so I'd count it as a bug to detect and fix there if there's an exception).

To behaved differently in such a case, then e.g. `.Select(error => error.Exception == null ? "No Error" : error.Exception.Message)`.